# Can TeX tell me where it is breaking the lines and pages?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking

I am looking for TeX to tell me where in the TeX file it has broken the lines and pages. I put \label in every word or even character and then it does tell me something but sometimes it is still thinking when it is answering. I know that it is difficult to do this in all possible TeX inputs but is there a reasonable solution to a reasonable TeX input?

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language, how do you want the results returned? if a page breaks in a table of contents "where in the file" did the page break happen?

Comment: Let us assume for simplicity that there are no generated text and transpositions or juxtapositions at all, then is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

`\showoutput` will cause the information you want to be put in the log file, getting the information in tex might be harder (unless you use luatex)  but it depends what form you want the information.