# Can TeX produce an expanded TeX as an output format similar to PDF?

Tags: output, output-routine

I am looking at TeX as an output format similar to PDF that describes the page sufficiently, but with all tokens resolved (more like going from Postscript to PDF).
This format should also indicate all the places where the linebreaks and pagebreaks are present as requested in a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213377/can-tex-tell-me-where-it-is-breaking-the-lines-and-pages). To put it more aptly, you could say that I am looking at TeX version of DVI which can reproduce the same DVI (though not necessarily identical).

Comment: Do you just want to complete expansion without any typesetting?

Comment: There has been some question in this regard, where the OP requested a way to resolve all macros into primitives... I think.

Comment: Short answer, no, but as werner said this is a duplicate, if we can find it...

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this would be to use `\showoutput` so that a symbolic form of every page is output to the log file then parse that page to produce a tex representation, but why?

Comment: Regarding why I want this is that I would like to use TeX as a software library for other pagination systems, which could even be TeX itself!

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201/15925

Comment: There are re-opening votes on the post. I decided to vote to leave it closed. The question might not be a duplicate anymore, but it's completely unclear what you actually want.

Comment: I am looking at an output representation using TeX markup, what more clear can I make it?